# Strange movement in XNA Snake Game

Tags: c#, xna

I've been trying to make a snake game in XNA, but I've come across a bug that causes the snake to get *all messed up*.

[image: Snake getting wicked]

As you can see, every new piece of the snake that spawns, whenever I pick up a "point", is shifted a bit to the side of the original piece.

When the game starts, the snake only consists of one of these cubes.

Here is the code that spawns the new pieces of the snake.

```
private void PointCollision()
{
    if (snake[0].getRect().Intersects(pointRectangle))
    {
        point.position = PointPosition();
        pointRectangle = new Rectangle(
                            (int)point.position.X, 
                            (int)point.position.Y, 
                            point.texture.Width, 
                            point.texture.Height);

        score++;

        if (xVel < 0)
            snake.Add(
                new Player(snakeTexture, 
                            new Vector2(snake[snake.Count - 1].position.X + 20, 
                            snake[snake.Count - 1].position.Y), 
                            new Vector2(xVel, yVel)));

        if (xVel > 0)
            snake.Add(new Player(snakeTexture, 
                                    new Vector2(snake[snake.Count - 1].position.X - 20, 
                                    snake[snake.Count - 1].position.Y), 
                                    new Vector2(xVel, yVel)));

        if (yVel < 0)
            snake.Add(new Player(snakeTexture, 
                                    new Vector2(snake[snake.Count - 1].position.X, 
                                    snake[snake.Count - 1].position.Y + 20), 
                                    new Vector2(xVel, yVel)));

        if (yVel > 0)
            snake.Add(new Player(snakeTexture, 
                                    new Vector2(snake[snake.Count - 1].position.X, 
                                    snake[snake.Count - 1].position.Y - 20), 
                                    new Vector2(xVel, yVel)));
    }
}
```

What is causing this strange behavior?

Comment: What are `xVel` and `yVel`? Floats? Also, what are the dimensions of your grid? Do you have code that snaps the position of the textures to the grid?